# UIImagePickerController and application background modes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, mpmovieplayercontroller, avaudiosession

I’m building an application which supports both video playback and recording (not simultaneously, it’s just two separate features it provides). In order to make the videos play after the app enters background and gets back, I had to add an `App plays audio` item to `Required background modes` in the plist (I’m using `MPMoviePlayerController` for playback).

This, however, causes a problem with my video recording (I’m using `UIImagePickerController` for it). Basically, even after the picker is dismissed (either by the Cancel button or when it’s finished picking media), the app still keeps the audio recording session running.

If I remove the `App plays audio` item from the plist, the ImagePickerController’s audio session stops misbehaving, but then I can’t resume the playback of `MPMoviePlayerViewController` on switching to app from background mode.

Is there a way I can customise the handling of the audio session so that both the `MPMoviePlayerController` and `UIImagePickerController` can work properly?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what your saying. You are playing a video in the app and you want it to continue playing in the background? What audio recording session are you referring to? The UIImagePickerController's audio session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, there is a way you can customize the handling of the audio session for what you desire:  don't try to set the `App plays audio` setting.

instead, in your AppDelegate code (which is usually in AppDelegate.m from the simple wizard projects provided), supply code in the `applicationWillResignActive:` method that will stop the playback in your `MPMoviePlayerController`, and then use `applicationDidBecomeActive:` to resume the playback at the point at which you paused it if so desired.

this will not only allow the video to be resumed after a temporary pause, but it will allow you to save the state so that the video can be resumed in case the app is removed from memory or in case the user causes it to be quit.

Answer (score 1):

You can scratch the background modes and instead use notifications to pause/resume your player. See `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` and `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` in the [UIApplication class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728).

You can snag some code and see this implemented in [this class](http://code.google.com/p/cooliris-toolkit/source/browse/Classes/MovieView.m?r=e57b03fa47b60012428f1b953001751ef165963f). Here is some of the relevant code from that class:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(_didBecomeActive:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(_willResignActive:)
                                             name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                           object:nil];

- (void) _didBecomeActive:(NSNotification*)notification {
  if (_wasPlaying) {
    [_movieController play];
  }
}

- (void) _willResignActive:(NSNotification*)notification {
  _wasPlaying = _movieController.currentPlaybackRate != 0.0;
  if (_wasPlaying) {
    [_movieController pause];
  }
}
```